# Differential and lone $dx$es and the dependence on a free parameter

Tags: derivatives, differential

Suppose I get the an equation like

$$ \frac{ds(t)}{dt} = \sum_i \frac{ds_i(t)}{dt} ,$$

as the result of some computation. In order to simplify this further I invoke the notion of the [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) whereby $ds=s'(t)\, dt$ and multiply the whole equation with $dt$ to arrive at

$$ ds = \sum_i ds_i\,. $$

While this looks simpler and in particular looks like it is independent of $t$, I wonder whether this is rather self deception, or whether this is indeed a meaningful simplification because the $t$, as a free parameter, plays only a technical role that need not necessarily be shown.

Does the answer depend on the meaning of the $s$ and the $s_i$. For example does it make a difference if the $s_i$ are points in space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a finite sum over $i$ here. The simplification you propose makes perfect sense.  In fact in Keisler's book all the basic laws for derivatives are formulated both in terms of derivatives and in terms of differentials.  Thus the product rule would take the form $d(uv)=udv+vdu$.  See [*Elementary Calculus*](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html).

Comment: Yes, finite sum. Nice book, thanks for the link.